# Git errors out when a submodule in the repo is switched to a different repo with other tree structure

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repo that uses a submodule A, and for technical reasons I need to switch the submodule to a submodule B, which is a different repo with different commits, they only shared a couple of commits from the beginning of the project, which is okay to me.

What I've done so far is:

1. Modify the`.gitmodules` file to use the new URL
2. Delete the submodule folder in the repo `rm -rf .git/modules/<submodule>`
3. Delete the submodule folder in the working directory `rm -rf <submodule>`
4. Run `git submodule sync`
5. Run `git submodule update`

After that I get an error:

```
fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref a5129baec669f7736552019baccd3da7e5129cfd
Fetched in submodule path 'Submodule/path', but it did not contain a5129baec669f7736552019baccd3da7e5129cfd. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
```

So the commit with the SHA `a5129b` exists in the submodule A as the most recent commit, but is not in the submodule B.

I don't understand why is trying to fetch the commit from the previous submodule, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce this and fixed it with these commands:

```
git submodule set-url <submodule> <old url>
git submodule update
git submodule set-url <submodule> <new url>
git submodule update
git -C <submodule> fetch
git -C <submodule> reset --hard origin/HEAD
```

**WARNING:** This will erase any uncommitted changes in `submodule`!

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me.